# Include a newline in a panel

Tags: jsf, escaping, newline, panel

How can I include a newline in a panel like as possible in the below outputtext?

```
<h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />
```

This does not work in a panel, as a panel does not have an `escape` attribute.

I tried including `<br />` or `\n`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: What exactly are you talking about when you say "panel"? No such thing exist in [standard JSF](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/). Some concrete code would greatly help in bridging this language/terminology barrier. Also, showing the raw HTML output of the desired result would be helpful in better understanding what you're ultimately trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you provide any sort of sample code? Your sample code saves your thousand words!

Comment: Can you add an example of panel? or provide link for what actually you are meaning with panel?

Answer (score 0):

In JSF , `h:panelGrid` tag is used to generate HTML table tags to place JSF components in rows and columns layout, from left to right, top to bottom. for example if you want to have something like bellow:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
    Enter a number : 
</td>       
<td>
    <h:inputText id="number" value="#{dummy.number}" 
        size="20" required="true"
        label="Number" >
        <f:convertNumber />
    </h:inputText>
</td>
<td>
    <h:message for="number" style="color:red" />
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

you can use `h:panelGrid` like bellow:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">

<h:outputText value="Enter a number :"/> 

<h:inputText id="number" value="#{dummy.number}" 
    size="20" required="true"
    label="Number" >
    <f:convertNumber />
</h:inputText>

<h:message for="number" style="color:red" />

</h:panelGrid>
```

So as adding only `<br/>` as table data in any row does not make any sense, like that adding

```
 <h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />
```

(or `<br/>`)in `h:panelGrid` also does not make any sense!

For details, you can see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-panelgrid-example/).